# AJAX Replace Glitchy on custom theme

Tags: theming, ajax

I have a form in my module that uses an ajax callback to replace input fields.

It's working on themes that come with drupal. However on a custom theme, it's glitchy. The replace happens, however the changes aren't displayed until i hit submit and the validation errors are triggered.

I'm really not sure why this happens.

If anybody has any idea why this happens, please let me know.

This is the theme i have issues with

http://drupar.com/theme/hertzpro

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Since the question is about code, you should show the code you are referring to. It is hard to explain what the code is eventually doing without seeing it.

Comment: Also, Stack Exchange is not to get ideas, but to answer well-formed questions with a definitive answer.